# Mediasoup server deployment to google cloud app engine platform

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, deployment, google-cloud-platform, webrtc

Is it possible to deploy a [mediasoup](https://mediasoup.org/) server to the **google-app-engine** ?

Tried for a very long time, and had no success so far. The official docs say, the ip should passed to the **rtcAnnouncedIPv4** parameter of the [mediasoup](https://mediasoup.org/) server settings, but I'm really confused how this could be done because Ip is changing every time. Do you have an idea, where the problem is and maybe give me a hint or a small sample? :) Thanks!

Comment: Do you give your vm static IP ? so the ip will not change every time .

Comment: Thanks for the reply. According to the official google docs its not possible to asign a static ip to google app engine apps. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/#static-ip says "App Engine does not currently provide a way to map static IP addresses to an application." Is there any way around this? Has anyone ever successfully deployed an mediasoup express app to google app engine?

Comment: sorry I did't realize it's on google-app-engine. maybe you can try this https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc ?

Comment: Looked into this sample already, not really an option. I need mediasoup because it implements SFU.

Comment: Got it working now. You specifically have to use google cloud computing engine, it doesnt work on google cloud app engine! Just pass a static ip to your instance and use th rtcAnnouncedIP4 Parameter in mediasoup server settings. Thanks for the hint with the static ip, it pointed in the right direction.